# Повторяющееся "безусловно" - вводное и наречие, - как быть с запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, наречия, невыделение-вводных

> Мебель этой спальни, безусловно, исполнена серьёзным мастером и так
>   же, безусловно, вторит идеям своей эпохи, «следует последним веяниям».

Это неправленый текст.

Права ли буду я, если:

*Мебель этой спальни безусловно исполнена серьёзным мастером и так
же безусловно вторит идеям своей эпохи, «следует последним веяниям».*

Comment: А не наоборот — первое вводное, а второе наречие? И ещё в вашем варианте получается, что "так же вторит", — странно как-то...

Comment: Тёмыч, НЕ ЗНАЮ. Отправлю. Автору интересно, обо что народ спотыкается.

Comment: Совершенно согласен с grizzly: не может быть и первое вводным. Действительно, так же безусловно, как и вводное безусловно, не может быть. Промелькнула мысль, что это странно, ещё вчера, но не остановился на ней.

Comment: Первое «безусловно»– вводное ( в запятых), второе – без запятых, «так же»–надо убрать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ исправлен.

*Мебель этой спальни **безусловно** исполнена серьёзным мастером и так же **безусловно** вторит идеям своей эпохи, «следует последним веяниям».*

**1) Читаем справочник**

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_50&v=full

БЕЗУСЛОВНО, вводное слово

То же, что «**конечно, без сомнения**».

«В ней, безусловно, есть индийская кровь», – решила Веда. И. Ефремов, Туманность Андромеды.

! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «**безоговорочно, полностью»**).

Агапов держал себя как **безусловно порядочный человек.** Т. Бек.

Не менее прочную позицию занимали в его душе немногие истины, добытые путем житейского опыта и **безусловно господствовавшие** над местностью. Л. Андреев.

2) **Пояснение**

Будем считать, что ***безусловно*** в обоих случаях является **наречием в роли обстоятельства** (по-другому не получается).

Наречие должно иметь грамматическую связь с предложением, а  вводное слово такой связи не имеет.

(1)  ...***безусловно  исполнена серьёзным мастером...***

Здесь наречие распространяет всё словосочетание ***исполнена серьёзным мастером***...

(2) ...***так же безусловно вторит идеям своей эпохи...***

Здесь сочетание ***так же безусловно вторит***.

Comment: Я не могу понять этого **так же**. Так же, как ... что? Как вводное слово *безусловно*? Разве такое допустимо?

Comment: Недопустимо, наверное. Пришлось внести "некоторые поправки". А что оставалось делать.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш безусловно хитрый автор двойным повторением слова хочет, безусловно, сделать акцент на преподносимой информации. Но вот на чем, где? Я видится так (с паузой *на втором* *"безусловно"*).

**Мебель этой спальни исполнена безусловно**(1) **серьёзным мастером и так же вторит, безусловно,**(2) **идеям своей эпохи, «следует последним веяниям».**

(1) = вполне, очень даже, бесспорно (указывается степень мастерства);
(2) = без всякого сомнения, в самом деле, точно (указывается степень достоверности сообщаемого).